# why browser trigger a click event instead of a submit in a form?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have this code
http://jsfiddle.net/2Gay9/3/

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="get" onsubmit="return false";>
    test: <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('input').bind("keydown click", function(event){
    console.log(event.type);
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

Try hit RETURN in input text and look console:

```
keydown
jQuery(input)
click
jQuery(input submit)
```

**QUESTION:** Why browser is triggering a 'click' event on submit button, instead of trigger a 'submit' event in the form? Is this a project flaw or a specification? How can I cancel second event WITHOUT cancel form submission?

Tks

**UPDATE**
In other words, I just need to diferenciate my event from browser event.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763638/enter-triggers-button-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

If I cant stop click event on submit button, I can workarround only diferenciating browser from users click. To diferenciate `browsers click` from `users click` I will use **mousedown** event instead of **click** event.

Every time we hit RETURN in a input text, browser trigger click on first submit button in current form. But this don't trigger mousedown event, "exclusive for humans" in this case.

Fixed version, that prints event once.

```
jQuery('input').bind("keydown mousedown", function(event){
    console.log(event.type);
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Gay9/6/

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
jQuery('input').bind("keydown click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.type);
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

Comment: I dont want do stop form submission because I have a lot of js that depends on this. I want just to diferenciate my event from browser event.

Comment: you mean custom events/event delegation?

Comment: No. I just want to know if a user clicked in submit button or if this click was triggered by browser.